# ReactJS: how to hide element based on parent's props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that is showing message box. It's called from the parent element something like that:

```
<AlertMessage status={this.state.status} text={this.state.text} />
```

I want to change it to take one more parameter hide and it would be hiding itself in 5 seconds:

```
<AlertMessage status={this.state.status} text={this.state.text} hide={true} />
```

The problem this alert message is based on props, so its render function looks like:

```
render(){
        const statusName = this.props.status || 'info';
        const alertStyle = 'alert-box ' + alertClasses[statusName] + (this.props.text ? '' : ' d-none');
        return (
                <div className={alertStyle}>
                    <span>{this.props.text}</span>
                </div>
            );
}
```

So, I see 2 ways to implement hiding after 5 seconds:

1. A parent element does it just setting up the text to ""
2. The alert component hides itself.

I don't want to involve the parent component here but I don't know how I would implement it inside alert component. Add more state like "hidden" to the alert component but how I would handle it after?

Update. I think I found the solution. I use static function getDerivedStateFromProps and the component's visibility is based on its state hide, not on the text:

```
    static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
        if (prevState.text != nextProps.message && nextProps.message){
            return {
                text: nextProps.message,
                hide: false
            };
        } else {
            return {};
        }
    }

render(){
        const statusName = this.props.status || 'info';
        const alertStyle = this.state.hide ? ' d-none' : 'alert-box ' + alertClasses[statusName];
        if (!this.state.hide){
            setTimeout(() => this.setState({hide: true}), 5000);
        }

}
```

There is still bug: when I show several messages in a row the total timeout will start on the first, not on the last, but it's okay for now.

Answer (score 1):

It will be difficult to handle it properly without involving the parent element. If you clear the `text` prop on parent, the `AlertMessage` component will still be mounted, but will be no visible due to no content inside. The same situation if you would drop the logic inside `AlertMessage` - you can't "unmount" the component directly from inside it.

The disadvantage is that `AlertMessage` remains mounted, you may have problems with applying animations to it. Also it may take the space in your app (depends on css), so users can accidently click on it or may cause problems with clicking elements placed under it.

What I would suggest - use your `hide` prop. Inside that function, where you set `hide` to `false` and the alert appears - use `setTimeout`, so the `hide` prop goes `true` after n seconds.

```
const someFn = () => {
   this.setState({ hide: false }); // alert appears
   setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ hide: true });
   }, 5000); // alert disappears (gets unmounted)
};
```

Then inside your render:

```
{!hide && <AlertMessage status={this.state.status} text={this.state.text} />}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think to unmount it, I just wanted to hide it.d-none style makes it invisible and not taking any space.

Answer (score 1):

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      hide: false
};
componentDidMount() {
    this.timer = setTimout(() => this.setState({ hide: true }), 5000)
}
componentWillUnmount() {
    this.timer && clearTimeout(this.timer);

render(){
    const statusName = this.props.status || 'info';
    const alertStyle = 'alert-box ' + alertClasses[statusName] + (this.props.text ? '' : ' d-none');
    return (
            <div className={alertStyle}>
                <span>{this.state.hide ? "" : this.props.text}</span>
            </div>
        );
}
```

Just get a state variable `hide`. setTimeout will turn it to false after 5 seconds. Don't forget to clear it in componentWillUnmount.

Comment: componentWillUnmount method is never called. So, after first hiding the hide is still true forever.

Comment: If there ever is logic in the parent component that will unmount the `AlertMessage` component before 5 seconds, there will be a memory leak. clearTimeout in  componentWillUnmount() will clean up after itself so it's good practice.

Comment: After you set up hide to true, it's never switched back to false, so after the first hiding the alert component is never shown again.

Comment: @mimic "_componentWillUnmount method is never called. So, after first hiding the hide is still true forever_" - I told you

Comment: @kinduser I think I found the solution, please see the update. I works exactly as I wanted - the component itself controls its visibility.

Comment: @mimic It's highly unrecommended to use setState inside render, even if a suitable condition is provided :( Still I think that the child cannot decide if to render itself or not to render.

Comment: @kinduser I totally understand. Can you suggest a better solution to meet the requirements?

Comment: @mimic You have my answer above:)

Comment: @kinduser Your solution is probably how it's *recommended* but it doesn't meet my main requirement - all the functionality should be inside the component. Another question - who and why doesn't recommend allowing child component to decide if to render or not?